# Switching workspaces in xmonad using programmer dvorak keyboard layout (shifted numbers)

Tags: haskell, keyboard, xmonad, ergonomics

Well, I am not using Dvorak actually but [Neo2](http://neo-layout.org), but as I am using a matrix type keyboard ([Truly Ergonomic](http://www.trulyergonomic.com/)) **I have also shifted the numbers.**

Therefore this construction in my `xmonad.hs` does not work ergonomically:

```
-- mod-[1..9], Switch to workspace N
-- mod-shift-[1..9], Move client to workspace N
--
[((m .|. modMask, k), windows $ f i)
    | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
    , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]
```

I want to change that, to be able to **access the workspaces 1 to 9 with the keys 2 to 0.**

How could I achive that? I have tried to change the third line to

```
    | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_2 .. xK_0]
```

but then I could not access the 9th workspace. How do I have to change this? A short explanition would be nice, so to learn something about this construction (I learned Haskell many years ago and forgot most of it).

Comment: Please share your config. I can't find a drop-in useable one anywhere. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that `xK_2` is bigger than `xK_0`, so the list `[xK_2 .. xK_0]` is empty:

```
Prelude XMonad> xK_2
50
Prelude XMonad> xK_0
48
Prelude XMonad> [xK_2 .. xK_0]
[]
```

You'll want to use a bit longer list than that. There's at least two reasonable ways to do this; one is to just specify all of keys yourself manually:

```
Prelude XMonad> [xK_2, xK_3, xK_4, xK_5, xK_6, xK_7, xK_8, xK_9, xK_0]
[50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,48]
```

What I would probably use is a bit shorter:

```
Prelude XMonad> [xK_2 .. xK_9] ++ [xK_0]
[50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,48]
```

Remember to add some parentheses if it's part of a bigger expression.

Comment: Quibble: `[a..b]` is an *arithmetic sequence* of an [enumerated type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.1/doc/html/GHC-Enum.html#t%3AEnum), not a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you. Similar to what I thought it would be.